# Could not find method implementation() for arguments - Gradle 7.3.3 JAVA 17 - intelliJ Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a root project build.gradle(:mainProj) file and 2 module level build.gradle(:modA) build.gradle(:modB)

> Previously the project was using below gradle version and was compiled on Eclipse Now using intelliJ-Idea:

```
`gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-bin.zip`
```

I've updated it to:

```
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip`
```

when I build the project it gets successful:

> `PS C:> gradle build`

> `Task :packageABC`
> `Engine Packaged Successfully...`

> `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s`
> `19 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 10 up-to-date`
> `PS C:>`

But then when I run the main file:

```
Build file 'C:\mainProj\modA\build.gradle' line: 21

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'modA'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [antlr:antlr:2.7.7] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Here's the build.gradle(:modA).

```
`repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'antlr:antlr:2.7.7'
    implementation 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.2.1'
    implementation 'com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:0.2.3.4'
    implementation 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2'
    implementation 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
    implementation 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.3'
    implementation 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-parent:2.2'
    implementation 'org.apache:apache:13'
    implementation 'org.apache:apache:16'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-parent:39'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    implementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:1.3'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:antlr:2.7.5H3'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final'
    implementation 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA'
    implementation 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20160810'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.11.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '4.3.11.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '4.3.11.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'amqp-client', version: '3.6.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.net.httpserver:http:20070405'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6'
}


configurations.all {
   exclude module: "slf4j-log4j12"
   exclude group:"org.slf4j", module: "log4j-over-slf4j"
   exclude group:"org.slf4j", module: "jul-to-slf4j"
   exclude group:"org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-over-log4j"
   exclude group:"org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
   exclude group: "ch.qos.logback.classic.log4j"
   exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j-api"
   exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}


jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
}`
```

`Previously it was compile instead of implementation I changed that since it was depreciated but found no luck.`

Comment: IS it possible to attach sample project example?

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue you've described, but it only occurs if I use "compile" instead of "implementation".
It would be very helpful if you could share your Project or a sample Project if the issue affects newly-created ones as well.